# Zend + Doctrine + PHPUnit = There is no open connection

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, phpunit

I'm trying to create unit test with phpunit for Zend, using Doctrine ORM. When I try to create a test class extending Zend_Test_PHPUnit_DatabaseTestCase, I get a message when executing PHPUnit: "There is no open connection"

Here is the full source:

```
<?php

class AclTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_DatabaseTestCase
{
    private $_userAdmin;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');

        $this->_userAdmin = Model_UserTable::getInstance()->findOneByUsername('admin');

        parent::setUp();
    }

    protected function getConnection()
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydbname', 'root', 'pwd');
        return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo, 'testdb');
    }

    protected function getDataSet()
    {
        return null;
    }


    public function testHasProfilPermission()
    {
        //execute some tests

    }
}
```

What do you think ?

Thanks

Comment: What versions of each are you running? Zend Framework 1.x doesn't work with the latest PHPUnit 3.6.

Comment: I'm using Zend Framework 1.11.11, Doctrine 1.2.4, PHPUnit 3.4.14 and the bridge ZFDoctrine

Answer (score 0):

Try this, please:

```
class AclTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_DatabaseTestCase
{
    private $_userAdmin;
    /** @var PDO **/
    protected $pdo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydbname', 'root', 'pwd');
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');

        $this->_userAdmin = Model_UserTable::getInstance()->findOneByUsername('admin');

        parent::setUp();
    }

    protected function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($this->pdo, 'testdb');
    }
}
```